# getString(R.string.MyString) not working when moved to a new class's method

Tags: java, android, class

This is probably a noob question.

I have a line of code that works when it's in a Class file that was created by Android Studio and is within the method of the button used, lets call it MainActivity. The line is:

```
File myNumbersFile = new File((Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + getString(R.string.my_numbers_file))).toString());
```

But when I move it to another Class file, that I created myself, just to split up the code, and put it in its own method the getString(R.string.my_numbers_file) part stops working.

The calling of the method is good as I can return values that are created before this line.

the logcat output is:

`07-08 20:52:48.646    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/LottoDownload/my_numbers.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-08 20:52:48.646    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:420)
07-08 20:52:48.646    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
07-08 20:52:48.646    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
07-08 20:52:48.646    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker.variousMethods.obtainCurrentNumbersArray(variousMethods.java:74)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker.CheckerActivity.populateButton(CheckerActivity.java:42)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:404)
07-08 20:52:48.656    5359-5359/au.com.acent.ash.basiclottochecker W/System.err﹕ ... 18 more`

The error only occurs at runtime, the compiler lets it through.

Please help or point me to another question that answers this.
Thanks

Comment: `my_numbers.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` is the exception...

Comment: seems to me like your new class is in another package, and thus the path to the file you are trying to use is different

Comment: The code may be OK but at runtime, the file /storage/emulated/0/Download/LottoDownload/my_numbers.txt is not found.

Comment: clean & rebuild your project

Comment: opps, sorry, I pasted the wrong logcat output *noob*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) is method from Context class. So you need context object while using inside of your class.*

Use `context.getString(R.string.my_numbers_file)`

---

You can do it via passing context object to the method in which this code block you are using.
Like

```
public void yourMethod(Context context) {
     File myNumbersFile = new File((Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + context.getString(R.string.my_numbers_file))).toString());

}
```

Comment: MAAAAAATE! That was it! And to call the method I use `thatClass.yourmethod(this)`  right?

Comment: @Ash Yes you are perfect! Better is to use `thatClass.yourmethod(ActivityName.this)`

Comment: Ahh, that ensurers that the context of the correct activity is sent? (oh, and I like being called perfect!)

Comment: Yes, this ensures that you are passing the activity object (as context) even if you use this code block from any inner class. Like callbacks we have (onclick listeners etc.). If you use `this` from any inner class it means you are passing an object of that inner class not activity. So this makes safe to use ActivityName.this from anywhere (Non Static) inside Activity. Hope now I am clear..

Answer (score 0):

You can access any of the string resources is with a `Context` (i.e. an Activity or Service). What I've usually done in this case, is to simply require the caller to pass in the `context`.
i.e. you should use

```
mContext.getString(R.string.my_numbers_file)
```

instead of

```
getString(R.string.my_numbers_file)
```

Note : `mContext` is the Context of Activity from where you are calling your class.